# xslt group by in multiple nodes

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

A sample structure of my input xml looks as below:

```
    <Products>
  <Product>
    <ID>Product1</ID>
    <Extra1></Extra1>
    <Extra2></Extra2>
    <Img1>val1</Img1>
    <Img2>val2</Img2>
    <Img3>val2</Img3>
    <Img4>val1</Img4>
  </Product>

  <Product>
    <ID>Product2</ID>
    <Extra1></Extra1>
    <Extra2></Extra2>
    <Img1>val1</Img1>
    <Img2>val2</Img2>
    <Img3>val2</Img3>
    <Img4>val1</Img4>
  </Product>
</Products>
```

I am parsing each `product` element at a time and grouping the `Img` tags of each product by its value. I am using `<xsl:key name="keyImg" match="Product/*[contains(local-name(), 'Img')]"
           use="."/>`. But the same key is used over and over again. Will it be an issue if two product contains same value for some `Img` tag? I am not sure if there will be conflicts in such cases. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is your `<xsl:key>` definition based on `local-name()`? You should not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a two-part key, like this:

```
<xsl:key 
  name="keyImg" 
  match="Product/*[starts-with(name(), 'Img')]" 
  use="concat(generate-id(..), '-', .)" 
/>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="Product">
  <xsl:variable name="productID" select="generate-id()" />

  <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'Img')][
    generate-id() = generate-id(key(concat($productID, '-', .)))
  ]">
    <!-- ... --->
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

On a general note it's not ideal if nodes with the same semantic value (`Img`) have different names (`Img1`, `Img2`, etc). If you can do anything about it, just name them `Img`.

Answer (score 0):

**Q.** *But the same key is used over and over again. Will it be an issue if two product contains same value for some Img tag? I am not sure if there will be conflicts in such cases.*

Whether there is a "conflict" or not depends of the wanted result. Your key holds all Img* items with the same value in a list. With this key you can generate an unique list of all Img* values.

If the key should be unique for Img* values within one Product you may add the `generate-id()` or the "Product/ID" to the key.
Something like this:

```
<xsl:key name="keyImg" match="Product/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Img')]"
             use="concat(../ID, '|', .)"/>
```

If the name of Img* tages is well known you may also try this:

```
<xsl:key name="keyImg" match="Img1 | Img2 | Img2 | Img4"
             use="concat(../ID, '|', .)"/>
```